# Code injection in .NET

Tags: .net, code-injection

Suppose you have an assembly `A` containing a bunch of pretty standard non-obfuscated classes.

Is there a way to programmatically create some sort of "mocking" assembly `B` that will contain all the methods located in assembly `A` but all these methods in assembly B should have a user-code injected in the start of the method and in the end, so that when assembly `B` us executed, it would run as normal + injected user code is executed. The injected code will be used for profiling purposes. Is it possible to accomplish somehow (I'm already using a ANTS profiler, so no need in any profiling tools, I'm just interested in whether it is possible to solve the problem the specified way)

Thank you!

## EDIT

Guys, I'm talking about writing a separate application (similar to http://codeinject.codeplex.com/) capable of taking any .net assembly as an input and producing the other one, that will contain:

1. all code of the first one
2. special user-code injected into every method of the assembly being... Well, being "mocked"

Suppose we have the following code:

**AssemblyA.dll:**

```
class Test
{
    void Action1(int someArgument)
    {
       ...
    }

    void Action2(bool someBool)
    {
       ...
    }

    public void DoSomeAction()
    {
        Action1(123);
        ...
        Action2(true)
    }
}
```

**Injector.dll:**

```
public class Injector: IInjector
{
    Dictionary<String, Int32> profiler = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

    void BeforeInvoke(IMethodCall call)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("A method {0} being called", call.Method.Name);
    }

    void AfterInvoke(IMethodCall call)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("A method {0} was called, duration {1}", call.Method.Name, call.Duration);
    }
}
```

It will allow do the following:

```
> inject.exe AssemblyA.dll Injector.dll AssemblyB.dll
```

Now when you reference AssemblyB.dll, and use in production environment, it would do everything the AssemblyA.dll does, but it would also perform some performance logging that can be later reviewed and analysed in more dev-like fashion.

## My question:

Where should I start looking?

Comment: [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) comes to mind, as does the below mentioned [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) for AoP, as well as the general pattern of interception employed when using IoC. None of these are as free as your `inject.exe`, but all of them are a viable mechanism of *how* the mythical application could be written.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much control you have over assembly A. If you build assembly A yourself, you can use aspect oriented programming (AOP) to inject the code you want to execute before and after each method. A popular tool to achieve this is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) that injects the code into the IL. Have a look at [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/logging). There also is a free Express edition.
It is much more difficult for assemblies that are not under your control:
If the assembly is not strong named or if you have access to the signing key, you can disassemble it, e.g. with [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the /out parameter. You can then inject the new codes into the IL file and assemble the file again using [ILASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  - an endeavor that is of course not all too easy, but the only way I can think of that allows to profile all calls. Keep in mind that also legal issues might arise if you are not allowed to disassemble assembly A and respect them.
If you access all of A's methods through an interface or you only want to add the code to virtual members of the classes, you can use an Inversion of Control container to intercept the calls (see CodeCaster's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912330/642579)). This is feasible with reasonable effort, but as the interceptions are done at runtime will degrade performance a bit.
Another approach is to use reflection and [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to analyze the types in assembly A and create code that wraps the calls to the methods. This way, you can also profile non-virtual, public members. Of course, internal calls in assembly A are not profiled.

Comment: No, it is not strong named, I just want to profile my application, but instead of using StopWatch or ANTS profiler, I want to profile each method automatically, I'm aware that this might lead to some performance degradation, but it's not that big deal. The Reflection + CodeDom is interesting approach but unfortunately it would require to mimic every CLR construct and it is a way to writing another Reflector, maybe there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: If you want to profile your own assemblies you can use AOP to inject code before and after each method. I will include a link in my answer.

Comment: I'm working on a fairly large project, around two years of development by 10-20 developers, incorporating system-wide framework at this point in time is not feasible, we will be not able to cover even more or less significant part of the code with it. It would be great if we could just choose the methods we want to profile and collect timings that we are interested in, not sure if we can do that with AOP

Comment: Or I may be wrong... Thank you for your time, I will surely look into AOP

Comment: AOP provides the basic mechanism. You can define the "aspects" - the code that should be executed, e.g. before and after a method call. In addition, you define where to integrate the code. As for PostSharp, aspects are implemented as attributes. You can add the attributes at assembly level and specify which methods the aspects should be applied to, e.g. by namespace or accessibility level (e.g. only public methods).